# In Android Shared post from my app using Facebook sharing dialog is showing to me but not to others . Why?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have attached Facebook sdk to my application correctly and managed to share post on my timeline using FacebookDialog. But my problem is that It is only showing to me but not to others. I don't know what i forgot to do. Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Make your app open for public in the Facebook Dev console- I dont remember the exact place to do this but there is one option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Submit** your app for review since it includes publishing functionality. See here from details- [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login)

   Without submission and approval, your app **wont** be able to publish on the user's wall.
2. Make your app public from the App Settings.

[image]

Comment: hey its working now. Can you tell me why it doesn't show description when i give link of playstore and when i give link of other website it displays correct description. Why? What i need to do for showing correct description.

Comment: Which API are you using? It would be better if you can post a new question with relevant details

Answer (score 1):

Goto developers.facebook.com 
Click on Apps select your app.

Then in "Status and Review" section change your App's Status to public.

Answer (score 0):

setting => apps => at app you want to show orther, at right, choose 'edit settings' => at top, 'App visibility and post audience'change to your idea :D
hope to help you :3